# "Two-key open mode" or "two open keys mode"?

Tags: word-order

Assume that we have an electrical circuit including two keys and a CPU. When the two keys are open the CPU switches to which of the following statements:

> two-key open mode

Or

> two open keys mode

Moreover, can we use "status" instead of "mode"? Can we also use "opened" instead of "open"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest **two-key-open mode**.  This is because "two keys being open" is a single descriptive modifier to *mode*.  "Two-key open mode" sounds like a specific kind of "open mode", which isn't right.  "Two open keys mode" is understandable but isn't how we usually use nouns as modifiers in English; for example, we say *two-car garage*, not "two cars garage".

*Open* is better than *opened* because *open* is simply the state of the keys, and *opened* puts the emphasis on an action that has occurred.

It's hard to say whether *status* is better than *mode* without knowing more about the system, but I suspect that *mode* is better.  [**Mode**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mode) means something like "a way of doing something", whereas [**status**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/status) means something more like "condition" or "state".  For example, a computer's *status* could be "removed in preparation for disposal", but that's not really a *mode*, since it isn't doing anything!